# Rearranging a simple algebraic equation

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

Suppose I have a simple algebraic equation like:

```
ChebyshevT[4, p] == 0
```

> ```
> 1 - 8 p^2 + 8 p^4 == 0
> ```

and I want to solve for the term `p^4` by simple rearrangement:

```
p^4 == -(1 - 8 p^2)/8
```

How do I do that in *Mathematica* ? And how can I then assign the solution to replace.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are aiming for but you could get what I think is your desired form by the following:

```
sol=Solve[1 - 8 p^2 + 8 p^4 == 0 /. p^4 -> u, u]
u/.sol[[1]]
```

This yields:

> ```
> 1/8 (-1 + 8 p^2)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that. For example, this:

```
    Clear[eq1, eq2, p];

eq1 = ChebyshevT[4, p] == 0;
eq2 = eq1 /. a_*p^4 -> a*x;
p^4 == Solve[eq2, x][[1, 1, 2]]
```

> ```
> p^4 == 1/8 (-1 + 8 p^2)
> ```

or this:

```
Clear[eq1, eq2, p];

eq1 = ChebyshevT[4, p] == 0;
eq2 = Map[Divide[#, -8] &, Map[Subtract[#, eq1[[1, 3]]] &, eq1]]
```

> ```
> 1/8 (-1 + 8 p^2) == p^4
> ```